# Cambiar idioma información required HTML 5

Tags: html5, required

Estoy haciendo una web en italiano en `HTML5`.
Tengo un formulario de contacto, con todos los campos con la etiqueta `requried=""` de `HTML5`.

Al darle a `submit` la info que sale debajo de cada `input`, sale en español, como puedo hacer para qeu salga en italiano.

Asi está el `doctype` y la etiqueta `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="it" xml:lang="it" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Creo que el mensaje aparece en el idioma del navegador.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza la función [setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity), aplicada en cada uno de los elementos en los que quieras mostrar un mensaje distinto:

HTML

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" required />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$('#form input[type=text]').on('change invalid', function() {
    var campotexto = $(this).get(0);

    campotexto.setCustomValidity('');

    if (!campotexto.validity.valid) {
      campotexto.setCustomValidity('Ciao ragazzi!');  
    }
});
```

---

En el siguiente enlace de MDN encontrarás más información y otros ejemplos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#Customized_error_messages

Comment: Y no hay una forma que lo haga por defecto sin tener que añadir scripts?

Comment: He probado el código pero no funciona

Comment: A mi el ejemplo con jQuery de @Shaz tampoco pero los del enlace que ha puesto sí: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/nbs8pst1/2/   Sin JavaScript no vas a poder hacerlo porque los textos son cosa del navegador y el idioma depende del idioma en que este el navegador, si tu navegador estuviese en italiano los verías en italiano

Comment: Había cometido un pequeño error en el código que puse, ya lo corregí, disculpas!